# AWS Ubuntu 18.04 AMI package installation failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04, aws-code-deploy

Whenever an AWS autoscaling group launches new ubuntu instance and I try to install any package on that instance it gives me the following error:

```
[stderr]E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
[stderr]E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend),
```

Is there another process using it?

I tried to find a solution and manually fixed it but I don't know why whenever the autoscaling group launches a new ubuntu instance it gives the following error.

Comment: Is something else also running there, e.g. SSM's State Manger?

Comment: This happens if you try to use `apt` when some another instance of package manager is already running. Quick google points out that it might GUI-based package manager induced error. If you use graphics, consider killing this process before installing stuff.

Comment: So should I wait for the process to get end and then use apt again

Comment: @Marcin I have preconfigured codedeploy agent in the user data.

Comment: Could be that. Check [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-aws-auto-scaling.html#integrations-aws-auto-scaling-behaviors). The problems that CodeDeploy agent may cause with asg are documented.

Comment: @Marcin the problem arises when I launch instances using ASG with preconfigured launch configuration with codedeploy agent installed. But when I launch ubuntu 18.04 instance manually from ec2 dashboard with codedeploy agent installed through user data then there is no problem.

Comment: You can try in your launch config suspend the agent at the benign `service codedeploy-agent stop` and then start it at the end. I think its an ordering of things that is causing issue.

Comment: @Marcin I can't stop codedeploy-agent as it is required to install application through appspec.yml file.

Comment: Please share the complete UserData script.

Answer (score 1):

When any command updates the Ubuntu or installs a new application, it locks the dpkg(Debian Package Manager).
To identify the problem, please look at the logs

1. If your system is installing some updates you may find journalctl logs `journalctl -u apt-daily.service`. This usually happend when the system is set to update itslef and you will notice such activity with this `ps -ef | grep apt.systemd.daily` and you can check these setting in the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`
2. `/var/log/dpkg.log*`(as it may get rotated) check these logs to find which all services were trying to get installed

Once you have identified the problem, you can solve with these methods:

1. If system is updating, then try to wait by executing sleep command in the `--user-data`of your bootstrapping script
2. If your 1st installation of an service/application is blocking other one, then put a condition to wait/sleep until the first service is up and so on with rest of the services you are installing.
   This was a common problem in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as per, and you can find the same with the solution code https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=251663

A snippet of code from the referenced link:
`until service codedeploy-agent status >/dev/null 2>&1; do
   sleep 60
    rm -f install
    wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-west-2.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
    chmod +x ./install
    sudo ./install auto
    service codedeploy-agent restart
done`

Answer (score 0):

SSH into the instance before/while the UserData is running and check which process has acquired the lock:

```
$ lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
```

Also, try to enable CodeDeploy agent at the last step after performing all other steps in UserData, like:

- https://gist.github.com/say8425/8344d19911dba20fab5538b85006bd31